# Problems with multiple text blocks

Tags: html, css

Here's my html for text boxes.. I want to display them "inline"

```
<div id="kutija_1">
   <center><h2> Text1</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
</div>
    <div id="kutija_2">
   <center><h2> Text2</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
</div>
    <div id="kutija_3">
   <center><h2> Text3</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
</div>
    <div id="kutija_4">
   <center><h2> Text4</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
```

Here is my css code:

```
#kutija_1 {
position:relative; 
width:25%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;
}
#kutija_2 {
position:relative; 
width:25%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;
}
#kutija_3 {
position:relative; 
width:25%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;
}
#kutija_4 {
position:relative; 
width:25%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;
}
```

Probably I don't need this "kutija_2, kutija_3,kutija_4".. 
My problem is that I only want to show these four boxes in one line. So i can put there news, contact stuff, quotes of the day etc...

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
display:inline-block;
```

To the blocks - **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LzY6Z/)**

Also, why do you need to use `IDs` if you're applying the exact same styling to each item. You could just add a class of `box` for example, and then you don't need to duplicate all those rules.

Another thing, the `<center>` tag is deprecated, so don't use that, if you want to center text use `text-align:center` in the `CSS`.

Comment: Also, because of border width - boxes width can't be 25%, or fourth box will be moved down... http://jsfiddle.net/PCbP8/ and some margin should be added...

Comment: @nevermind
Thank you very much for your answer! Helped me a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float: left;` to 1 block and give all the divs the same class, so they appear inline.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bHKdA/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="kutija_1">
   <h2> Text1</h2>
<div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
</div>
<div class="kutija_1">
   <center><h2> Text2</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
</div>
<div class="kutija_1">
   <center><h2> Text3</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
</div>
<div class="kutija_1">
   <center><h2> Text4</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
```

CSS:

```
.kutija_1 {
position:relative; 
    float: left;
width:25%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;
}

.kutija_1 h2{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also note that i added `.kutija_1 h2{ text-align: center;)` do not use `<center>` this option is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

may i sure try this:

```
  #kutija_1 {
    position:relative; 
    width:25%;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:auto;
    border:3px black double;
    border-radius:14px;
    float:left;
    }
    #kutija_2 {
    position:relative; 
    width:25%;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:3px black double;
    border-radius:14px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 2px;
    }
    #kutija_3 {
    position:relative; 
    width:25%;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:auto;
    border:3px black double;
    border-radius:14px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 2px;
    }
    #kutija_4 {
    position:relative; 
    width:25%;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:auto;
    border:3px black double;
    border-radius:14px;
    float:left;
    }
```

Comment: That partially solved my problem..
Here's the thing now, it's not showing any spacing between these boxes :S

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the div to left

```
         #kutija_1, #kutija_2, #kutija_3, #kutija_4{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your IDs and add this class to all your boxes, it should do the trick

```
.text-box {
    position:relative;
    width:24%;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:auto;
    border:3px black double;
    border-radius:14px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Vvh9/

Answer (score 0):

```
#kutija_1 , #kutija_2 ,#kutija_3 , #kutija_4{
    display:inline-block;
width:23%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QUkQ6/)

**The Code:**

```
.kutija{float:left;}
```

If yes, here is the logic.

**The Logic:**

You need to just create a class called for instance, `.kutija` and apply it for all the `divs` that have `ids` already assigned. The attribute for this class should have `float:left;`. Thats it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of All the Total width is 100%, in which u want to have four equal columns. Even if you use `float:left` or `display:inline-block;` that wont align all 4 divs together. so you have given 25% width + border which will be more than 100% + border width. so 3 columns will appear and one will appear at the bottom.

With this u will not be able to align all four div's together. So what i would suggest is you can do something like this

I just changed the code a bit u can check the html

```
<div class="common">
   <div id="kutija_1"> 
   <center><h2> Text1</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
       </div>  
</div>
    <div class="common">
   <div id="kutija_2"> 
   <center><h2> Text1</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
       </div>  
</div>
    <div class="common">
   <div id="kutija_3"> 
   <center><h2> Text1</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
       </div>  
</div>
    <div class="common">
   <div id="kutija_4"> 
   <center><h2> Text1</h2></center>
    <div class="stripeContainer"></div><br><br><br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>asdfasdfasdffdaasdf<br>
       </div>  
</div>
```

Css would be something like this

```
.common{display:inline-block; width:25%; float:left;}
#kutija_1 {
position:relative; 
width:90%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;

}
#kutija_2 {
position:relative; 
width:90%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;

}
#kutija_3 {
position:relative; 
width:90%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;

}
#kutija_4 {
position:relative; 
width:90%;
margin-top:5px;
height:auto;
background-color:#fff;
overflow:auto;
border:3px black double;
border-radius:14px;
}
```